# confused what to use- Tomcat or java socket server

Tags: java, tomcat, socketserver

I want a piece of java code to run on a particular port.
for exampple `localhost:007` will return `{key: value}`
should i write a socket server in java, or should I use Tomcat?

Comment: That is a question that depends on many factors, what you need, what you want, etc.

Comment: Does it need to actually accept HTTP requests and produce HTTP responses, or do you just want to accept a connection, dump `{key:value}` back the client and be done with it?

Comment: no, it doesn’t need to accept HTTP request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beautiful thing about Java is that there are so many existing libraries and frameworks out there that there's almost always an existing tool or framework to solve your problem. It will save you a heap of time to use Tomcat or some other lightweight container like [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) for this task.

Alternatively, if this is a learning exercise then writing your own simple web server sounds like good fun!